# Android Studio Preview

Tags: android-studio

I just opened a new project in Android Studio, but the preview screen isn’t working. It should show “Hello World!” right now, but it’s blank. When I go to other projects I’ve completed, the preview doesn’t show up there either.

I’ve reinstalled the program and I’m googling ways to fix the problem. If anyone has had this problem and fixed it, or just has an idea of what to do, I’d greatly appreciate the help! I will attach a screenshot of my Android Studio. [Android Studio w/ preview problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0SIs.png)

Thanks

Comment: try changing the api level and device in the preview screen

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I changed them, but they remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your preview window in android studio ?
I am asking to you because I was also in the same problem a month ago.
If yes, In The Preview Window. There Will Be A Error Symbol On that window.
Tap on that it will show you the reason for preview error. Fix it and now it works perfectly in my pc.
**Edit 1:**
Exact Solution after your comment
Tap On That Blue Dot
It would tell preview fidelity issue for the session. Mute The Fidelity Issue For The Session From Same Window And You Are Good To Go.

Comment: I don't have any Error Symbols. The only thing that was there is a blue dot in the top left corner. I wish there was some kind of customer service for android studio, because now I'm having other problems with it too.